# Superset not showing Alert/Reports in "Settings" drop down

Tags: python, configuration, apache-superset

So I have installed Apache Superset 1.0.1 on an EC2 instance (in virtual environment).

Now, i created a file named `superset_config.py` which has the following content:

```
ENABLE_ALERTS =True
ENABLE_SCHEDULED_EMAIL_REPORTS = True
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    "ALERT_REPORTS": True,
    "THUMBNAILS": True
}
```

After doing this, I add it to my pythonpath via : `export PYTHONPATH="$PWD/superset_config.py"`

After this, I run `superset init` and then launch superset on a port. However I still cannot see the alerts and reports options in the srop down menu, as shown below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and what do I need to change?

Answer (score 3):

In superset_config.py, refer this [changelog](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/UPDATING.md), there are certain config changes:

```
ENABLE_ALERTS = True
ENABLE_SCHEDULED_EMAIL_REPORTS = True
DEFAULT_FEATURE_FLAGS = {
  'ALERT_REPORTS': True
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your "List Roles" and include point of alerts\reports menu in list of the role

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).